# Rendering progress bar doesn't show me the total percentage

Tags: rendering

Hi I have some questions regarding status bar when doing the render.

1. when rendering animation, i can see the progress bar, but it only showing the progress of current frame rendering. Is there any setting i can show the total progress so far ? How many percentage of frames has been rendered ?
2. Also there's no information about total frame number and how many frames at current render job in the status bar. I only can see the current frame being process. I have to check timeline and render tab to see this information. Any other tips ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a way. What would be the drawback of having a small timeline open at the bottom of the window? The length, current frame numer and progress can be easily read from it.